# Windows File Handle Limit

Tags: windows

Is there a way to determine and tweak the file handle limit in Windows?

Comment: Go on, I'll bite, what version? 98 and below is was the 'files=' statement in config.sys ;)

Comment: How about Win XP?

Comment: In which case this is a superuser.com question - that said take a look here; http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx

Comment: You'd be surprised how many Win98/XP/2000 "servers" are still floating around (Lawyers Never Upgrade :-( )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For crusty old DOS and Win16 programs:

Windows 98 and earlier: `FILES=` statement in `config.sys`

Windows NT/2000/XP (Probably Vista & 7): `FILES=` statement in `\Windows\System32\config.nt` (Possibly also a registry setting?)

---

For Windows native programs (Win32 API): Shouldn't Apply (Per MSDN, there is no fixed file handles limit on the Win32 API, unless I'm misunderstanding).

If you're hitting the system global (kernel) file handle limit you have bigger issues to address.